# Span won't right align in footer

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a few span elements filling up my footer, and I am trying to get the copyright span to be right aligned, rather than bunched together with all the other elements. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
<footer>

    <span>Blog</span><span>Hire</span><span>About</span><span id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2012 Max Kramer</span>

</footer>

footer {
    width:  50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

footer span {
    display: inline-block;
}

footer span #copyright{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, remove the space between span and it's ID - they are the same element, not an ID nested inside a span. second, use float, not text align :)

```
footer span#copyright{
  float: right;
}
```

you can also just do this:

```
footer #copyright{
  float: right;
}
```

you also don't need to specify "inline-block" for spans - that's their default value for "display" anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A span is a flow object, meaning it don't have a width. To give it a width it needs to be a block element which will give you a width to right-align it to. But by making it `block`, it will be pushed down to the row below the other spans, which makes you need to float it right.

You need to:

```
#copyright {
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```